# Laravel: how change rules of validation in reset password

Tags: laravel, validation

If a user enters a wrong email when trying to reset a password, he receives an error message "passwords.user". I'm trying to override the methods of rules and messages of trait Auth/ResetsPasswords.php but my user gets all the same message

This is my controller

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use ResetsPasswords;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'exists:users.email',
        ];
    }

    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [
            'email.exists' => 'The email is not registered',
        ];
    }
}
```

trait method does not contain key 'passwords.user'

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

but it is in the folder config/auth

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

How can I add my own rules and error messages when resetting password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I have corrected the previous answer, because I was pointing to the wrong file

The file you are looking for, to translate your message is in `resources/lang/en/passwords.php` and there you can customize che `'user'` entry.

Of course if `en` is not your current locale, change that directory to your language

Comment: I did what you say, but the problem, unfortunately, did not dare

Comment: 'custom' => [
            'passwords' => [
                'users' => 'Електронна адреса не знайдена',
            ],
        ],

Comment: You should not add `custom`, but just add the `passwords` as key in the array returned by `validation.php`

Comment: PasswordBroker interface has const INVALID_USER = 'passwords.user';
It is this line that the user sees if he makes a mistake. Could you tell me how can I change this line?

Comment: I just need to translate this constant into another language, without a class extension

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You helped me a lot. Add a folder with the desired language and translate the necessary messages worked for me. =)